# Inserting in memory objects (datatable) to database by SSIS Packages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sqlbulkcopy, datamart

In Sql Server 2008, I need to create a large data mart.
I've written .NET Code (C#) for running all SELECT Stored Procs in parallel from code and join the results in datatable in memory.

I insert the datatable to database by SqlBulkCopy, but it gets really slow after some time.
I use table lock and i adjusted batch sizes, but still there is no performance gain.

How can I insert the Datatable into Sql Server 2008 database by creating SSIS package from code and run the package as an alternative to SqlBulkCopy?

Comment: What is your primary key strategy?  Natural Key, Surrogate Key (Int or Guid) or what?

Comment: I ve a bigint field as clustered unqiue index. There is no primary key or other types of constraint on table.

Comment: "I've written .NET Code (C#) for running all SELECT Stored Procs in parallel from code and join the results in datatable in memory" Why? you have a database - I suggest you don't try and rewrite database join logic in your own custom code. Also why would you create a SSIS from code? Why not just create the SSIS normally and run it?